# Hosting a web application on AWS using java, maven, spring and mySQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring, amazon-web-services, web-services

My son has done a university project which is a web app using Java 8, Maven, Spring boot, Spring hibernate, Spring data and MySQL. I am helping him try to find a free or very cheap hosting solution, and was told AWS is one option.  Is this correct?  The application is small (15 tables) and the data is a few megs.

If AWS is the way to go, am I supposed to setup a virtual / instance and install all software and upload all code to the virtual?  He is using Windows 10 to develop the application.  Which instance should be used?  There are various "Microsoft Windows Server" options.

A guide on how to do this and have it running on the web would be appreciated.

Comment: AWS has a free tier that applies for the 1st year after signing up. The catch is you must use the "free tier eligible" instance (typically a tiny one) and must install all necessary software you need on it (e.g. mysql and maven, I think Java is already included). There are equivalent free tiers on Azure or Google Cloud. Java can be ran on any OS so it doesn't matter what you choose. On the other hand this question is really open-ended, a more appropriate question for SO would have been to help resolve any specific issues setting up an instance.

Comment: I did ask if I was supposed to set up an instance or not.  All the AWS options are daunting for someone seeing them for the first time.

Comment: Installation and running the app was easy.  The fiddly part was getting the inbound connection rules added so that outside connections were possible.  Sorry for the "open-ended" question but as I used AWS for the first time, I needed conceptual answers.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't an entire guide, but a starting point to check on your options. 
All depends on for how long you intend to have the application running.
If you only want to have a demonstration of the APP in School you could really use the AWS Free tier for new users.

If you intend to have it running for more than a year or scale it up, you will either have to refactor it as Micro services based architecture or a payment will be required, though it isn't really that much at all.

I sugges you have a look here:

https://aws.amazon.com/free/

https://aws.amazon.com/answers/web-applications/aws-web-app-deployment-java/

https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/pricing/

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  We will check the links later.